# Alternatives to the default font for letters to be used in the list of symbols?

Tags: fonts, formatting, symbols

I am writing the symbol list and I am having problems because different physical quantities use the same symbol and therefore I need a different font (possibly not in math mode, so not inclined letter to avoid confusion with normal text) to avoid ambiguity. Below is an example where the letter `a` is used both as a symbol for the semi-major axis and as a constant distance (I included the most of packages used in my modular project):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pifont} % for dingbats
\usepackage[osf]{erewhon}% extension of Utopia, osf=old-style-figures
\usepackage[varqu,varl]{inconsolata}% sans typewriter
\usepackage[scaled=.95]{cabin}% sans serif
\usepackage{textcomp}% AFTER newtxtext to avoid clashes
\usepackage[TM]{ar}

\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{fixmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

$a$ %alternatives for a different symbol for letter a not in math mode?

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately I cannot use another symbol since I have many equation with the letter `a` and I would want to mantain that letter.

P.s. I think this issue can occur for other symbols, hence consider this question about other letters too.

Comment: I think it's generally a bad idea to use the same variable for two different purposes. Even with a different font it is likely to confuse the reader. Maybe `\mathfrak{a}` or `\alpha`?

Comment: Thank you @SandyG. I will try to change symbol to avoid ambiguity. However your solution seems to be acceptable.